# What is the use of a refresh token in a JWT auth if both access and refresh token are in a httpOnly cookie?

Tags: cookies, jwt

**The problem**

I am trying to implement a good but simple auth for my web app so my choice was using JWT.
But as I was searching about JWT something made no sense to me :

1. The access token, with a short life, needs to be stored in a secure httpOnly cookie
2. The refresh token, with a long life, needs to be stored in a secure httpOnly cookie. It is used to give it to the server on a /refresh path to generate a new access token when it expires.
3. When you want to access some routes in your server, the httpOnly cookies will be given to auth you automaticaly. So you will give both access and refresh tokens!

I don't understand the use of having a refresh token if you give it to each request as you can't only give the access token when they are stored in a httpOnly cookie. If someone does the middleman and catches your request and then gives it to the server, then he/she will have both access and refresh token no?

Am I missing something?

**Some solutions that I don't understand**

- I read a lot of people saying that the good way is to have the refresh token in the backend, but how can the front refresh the access token if he does not have the refresh token? What do you send to the backend?
- Having both httpOnly: as I described above I can't understand how it is useful to send both access and refresh tokens with every request, having only one token would be the same
- Having the access token in a normal cookie and the refresh token in an httpOnly cookie: I can understand that it allows you to send only the access token for your normal requests, and you can use the refresh token only for the /refresh endpoint. But your access token is completely vulnerable, so people can use it with javascript injection in your code and mess with your data.

The best thing I thought of was not sending the refresh token with my normal requests but I read that it is impossible, you either send everything or nothing if it is an httpOnly cookie.

What do you think, is there really no way to do better than that? Is the easy JWT auth way flowed so I need to use something better to be sure that my auth system is secure ?

**Note**

I don't think it is important but I am using node (express) and angular for my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to implement a good but simple auth for my web app so my choice was using JWT.

If you want a simple auth for your website then go with sessions. Don't bother using JWTs. As you noticed when you're trying to use access and refresh tokens in a way that you would use sessions, then it gets a bit weird in some parts.

That said, if you want to stick to tokens and cookies, here are some explanations.

1. You can configure your refresh token cookie to have a path `/refresh` so that the cookie is only sent to the refresh endpoint. This will prevent the problem that you mentioned, that someone would steal both cookies.
2. About the backend refreshing the token. This describes a setup where you have an additional component that stores the refresh token. This is usually used in a more advanced system, where you have separate APIs, an authorization server, and frontend apps. Then you have such a scenario: the front calls the API with the access token -> API returns 401 because the token is expired -> the front calls the additional backend component that stores refresh tokens -> the component calls the authorization server to refresh the token -> then the front can call the API again with the new token.

> Having both httpOnly: as I described above I can't understand how it is useful to send both access and refresh tokens with every request, having only one token would be the same

Yes, because you use these tokens as you would use a session. It seems that you have no need for a pair of tokens.

> Having the access token in a normal cookie and the refresh token in an httpOnly cookie

You're right. This is not safe and you should not go this way.